# Angular : 3rd party library library not found

Tags: angular, npm, node-modules, jquery-ui-slider-pips

I'm using some JQueryUI sliders in my (first) Angular application.

I want to use the JQuery-Ui-Slider-Pips plugin in order to add more information on my sliders. This library isn't available on npm, so i've add it into my assets directory and add this into my .angular-cli.json file

```
"styles": [
   "styles.css",
   "../node_modules/jqueryui/jquery-ui.css",
   "./assets/css/pips/jquery-ui-slider-pips.css"
],
"scripts": [
   "./assets/js/pips/jquery-ui-slider-pips.min.js"
],
```

I've also added this into my index.html file :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/pips/jquery-ui-slider-pips.css">

<script src="../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../node_modules/jqueryui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/js/pips/jquery-ui-slider-pips.min.js"></script>
```

I've imported jQuery and jQueryUI into my component.ts :

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'jqueryui';
```

And I initialize my slider in a specific method call during the ngOnInit() method :

```
initSlider(minValue, maxValue, stepValue, initialValue) {
$(this.elementRef.nativeElement).find("slider").slider({
  range: false,
  min: minValue,
  max: maxValue,
  step: stepValue,
  value: initialValue,
  slide: (event, ui) => {
    this.selectedValue = ui.value;
    this.sliderChanged();
  }
}).slider("pips", {
  rest: "label"
}).slider("float", {
})
;
}
```

But I have the following error :

"Error: no such method 'pips' for slider widget instance"

I guess the library isn't found at the execution of the script, but I have no idea why...

PS : I don't know how create an editable sample in something like JSFiddle for Angular 4, i'm pretty new on it.. but if necessary, with the appropriate link, I can provide this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my issue. I've changed my way to initialize my slider, putting it into a component.

The code, if it could provides help to somebody :

```
import { Component, ElementRef, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
declare var $: any;
declare var noUiSlider: any;

@Component({
    selector: 'app-slider',
    template: `<div id="mySlider" class="slider"></div>`,
    styleUrls: ['./styles/styles.css']
})

export class Slider implements OnInit {

    @Input() minValue;
    @Input() maxValue;
    @Input() stepValue;
    @Input() initialValue;
    @Output() sliderChanged = new EventEmitter();

    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.renderSlider();
    }

    renderSlider() {
        let that = this;
        $(this.elementRef.nativeElement).find("#mySlider").slider({
            range: false,
            min: +that.minValue,
            max: +that.maxValue,
            step: +that.stepValue,
            value: +that.initialValue,
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                that.sliderChanged.emit(ui.value);
            }
        }).slider("pips", {
            rest: "label",
        }).slider("float", {
        });
    }
}
```